# "find" cmd to search for files in sub directories as well

Tags: directory, find

I am currently having the below code to delete old log files

```
df -k /opt/logs/ ; find /opt/logs/*[.]log[.]* -mtime +5 -exec /bin/rm -fv {} \;
```

But the find command is not searching for **`*.log.*`** files in sub directories. How can I Make it search in sub directories as well

Answer (score 0):

Correct find syntax should be:

```
find /opt/logs -name "*.log.*" -mtime +5 -exec /bin/rm -fv '{}' \;
```